# d3 stacked bar chart - start at y0, not yMax

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this stacked bar chart: 
http://jsfiddle.net/maneesha/n7eLLnrm/2/

The problem is that it looks like the stacking starts at yMax and goes down, not at y0 going up.

This wasn't a problem and wasn't apparent at first when I had the same count (number of people) in each series (year).  Now that some years have more people I realize something is wrong.  Where do I fix this?

Some possibly relevant parts of my code:

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([height, 0]),
```

//////

```
rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function (d) {
        return d;
        })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
        })
    .attr('y', function (d) {
        return height - yScale(d.y0);
        })
    .attr('height', function (d) {
        return height - yScale(d.y);

        })
    .attr('width', function (d) {

        return xScale.rangeBand();
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code:

```
.attr('y', function (d) {
  return height - yScale(d.y0);
})
.attr('height', function (d) {
  return height - yScale(d.y);
})
```

to the following code:

```
.attr('y', function (d) {
  return yScale(d.y0 + d.y);
})
.attr('height', function (d) {
  return yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y0 + d.y);
})
```